# Jenkins file parameter plugin issue

Tags: file, jenkins, parameters

I am creating a Jenkins pipeline (declarative syntax) that accepts string and file parameters. String parameter is already available in declarative syntax. But to get file parameter in declarative syntax, the option we have is to use the [file-parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/#documentation).

This is how my Jenkins file looks like:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    base64File 'THEFILE'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        withFileParameter('THEFILE') {
          sh 'cat $THEFILE'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When you provide a file, it works, and the content of the file is printed.

But when you don't provide a file as parameter, pipeline should fail and complain about it. But it is not failing. Instead, that part of console output is saying:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Example)
[Pipeline] withFileParameter
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ cat /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-file-plugin@tmp/THEFILE18272962853430646509.tmp
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withFileParameter
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

That means, a temp file like `THEFILE18272962853430646509.tmp` is still created even if you don't provide one.

As per this [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-parameters/) :

> By default, there will be an error if there is no parameter for the
> build

Then why it is not failing?

Can anyone help me with a workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working as it's supposed to work. There are multiple ways to workaround this, here are two solutions, based on Shell and Groovy.

**Shell**

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    base64File 'THEFILE'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        withFileParameter(name: 'THEFILE') {
          sh '''
            cat $THEFILE
            if [ -s $THEFILE ]
            then
                 echo "File is not Empty!"
            else
                 echo "File was not specified or is Empty!"
                 exit 1
            fi
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Groovy**

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    base64File 'THEFILE'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        withFileParameter(name: 'THEFILE') {
            script {
                def fileContent = readFile("$THEFILE")
                if (fileContent.isEmpty()) {
                    error "File was not specified or is Empty"
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```